# Creating New-SPWeb from PowerShell & WebProvisioned Event Receiver?

Tags: powershell, event-receivers, spweb

I have a WebProvisioned event receiver and i do some work in this event receiver. When i create new webs from powershell, it seems the event receiver does not fire? Is this an expected situation? How can i make event receiver work, when i am creating items from powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it in the past so it should be working fine.

1. Are you running cmd-let with full (administrator) permissions?
2. Also make sure, account creating the webs have enough privileges to execute (i.e. full
   control of web application)?
3. Would you mind posting your `webtemp xml`, because there could be a problem with provisioning providers in `webtemp xml`, I have seen it so many times in the past.

Comment: thank you, the problem was my powershell window was open for a long time. so it does not take the updated version of the event receiver.